# How to get the sender of an e-mail in EWS MAPI? (C# UDATE 2023 OATH 2.0 GRAPH EWS API)

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, exchangewebservices

## C# Console Application

### Connect to EWS API via [Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph] 2.10.0

*All of the current answers are old on this one, submitting anew.*

I am using C# to connect to Graph API to connect to a mailbox via EWS API and I am trying to go through and read the sender of the email. The basic code is as follows:

```
IUserMailFoldersCollectionPage allMailFolders = await graphClient
    .Users[username]
    .MailFolders
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

foreach(var message in messages){
    Console.WriteLine("Sender: " + message.Sender.EmailAddress);
}
```

The email address is always "**Microsoft.Graph.EmailAddress**"

The only library in use is **Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph** version **2.10.0**

What doesn't work due to no reference or otherwise:

```
message.Sender.Address
message.Sender.Name
message.Sender.EmailAddress.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

I always end up doing this, but if anyone finds this, then here's the solution.

message.Sender.EmailAddress.Address